# How to split assets based on supported texture compression on an App Bundle?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

As described in tittle, how to split the assets folder on Android App Bundle based on devices supported texture compression. For example if the application support ASTC, ETC2, and ETC1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported yet unfortunately.

Comment: will it be supported in the near future?